# Is there any way to connect AWS to my Slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, amazon-web-services, slickgrid

I am looking forward to connect my Slickgrid to any of the AWS databases. After doing a lot of googling I haven't found much so I've decided to ask SO.

Is it simple to do it? If so, how would I do it following example 3 of the Slickgrid?
Like loading data from the DB and then have a "Save" button (or onCellChange) to save it back to the DB.

Maybe I should consider an alternative to the Amazon DB. If so, what would you recommend and how would you do it to connect the grid to the DB.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you jqxGrid, I really enjoyed it give a try, http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/createremoveupdatedata.htm

Comment: @believeme how do I connect the grid to the database though?

Comment: Look at this http://www.jqwidgets.com/jqxgrid-virtual-scrolling-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @believeme That example uses deprecated mysql library and has issues with SQL injection. While it does demonstrate the concept, the code needs to be improved before using it in production.

Comment: @datasage you're right I don't use this example anyways, I'm using PDO, this example is just for a beginning, its the matter of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a server side code component that will handle providing data and saving changes. This could be written in php/ruby/python or whatever you are comfortable with. Most languages have a driver or connector to any of the amazon databases whether its traditional relational databases on RDS or one of the NoSQL stores like simpleDB/DynamoDB.

Comment: could you give an example or tutorial? This would be my first time using AWS and I am a little lost.

Comment: This is a bit more involved than a simple tutorial. If you don't take the time to understand how it works, you may end up writing insecure code which could result in your server getting hacked. Look at the server side language options and figure out which you would like to learn. PHP is probably the easiest to configure and get started with. But also easy to write bad code.